# WP8 voice commands work only on emulator

Tags: windows-phone-8, voice

I've written a WP8 app that accepts voice commands. I've deployed and tested on the emulator and everything works fine. 
However, when deploying and testing on my HTC 8X the voice commands aren't detected, they don't even appear in the 'What can I say' option.

Anyone come across this before? Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the VCD CommandSet `xml:lang` attribute doesn't match the language and region combination used on your phone. What's the `xml:lang` for the CommandSets in your VCD file? And what's the language and region used by your phone?The default VoiceCommandDefinition1.xml file defaults to `xml:lang="en-US"`, so is your phone set to the English Language in the US region?

From a development perspective, you'll have to specify a CommandSet for each `xml:lang` supported by your app.

Also, remember that speech recognition only works for 15-20 cultures (language+region combinations). It could be your phone is one of the unsupported locales and you won't be able to support speech recognition for that culture at all.

Comment: I believe I am suffering the exact same issue, but am at a loss as to what language to specify. I tried "en-AU" and "en" but neither of these caused a match. Should I inspect CurrentCulture or CurrentUICulture?

Comment: Never mind, it's en-GB despite being labelled "English" without a qualifier. Which I suppose is reasonable given that "English" means "[language of] the people of England".